500 Status error with Devmode Off
My site loads perfectly fine when I have devMode set to true, but when I keep everything the same except turning devMode to false, it returns a 500 error (probably a server issue). I am really at a loss and not sure how to move on. I am new to craft, there are a lot of plugins if that matters.
This is my environment setup, if I keep everything the same here but change devMode to false I get a 500 Internal server error.
    'dev' => [
        // Dev Mode (see https://craftcms.com/guides/what-dev-mode-does)
        'devMode' => true,
        'baseCpUrl' => getenv('BASE_CP_URL'),
        'requireMatchingUserAgentForSession' => false,
    ],


This is my craftcms.local.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com
        ServerName mysite.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com/current/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/app/web

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
        <Directory /var/www/html/mysite.com/current/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/app/web>
                 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                 AllowOverride ALL
                 Require all granted
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>


and my .htcaccess file
php_value max_input_vars 2000
php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
php_value post_max_size 20M

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>



Have you checked your error logs? Specifically, storage/logs/phperrors.log could provide a clue.

Yeah this is where all the logs were hiding, looks like its the same redis password issue I came across while searching the bug. - Thank you!

In case this helps someone else - https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/7617
